# Several issues connecting to gmail via IMAP

Tags: java, gmail, google-oauth, imap, gmail-imap

For months we would observe the "* BYE SYSTEM ERROR" exception when attempting to retrieve all the e-mails in our inbox, with a frequency of 1 error per month (we run this thread daily)

This past month we got this exception almost every day. I never found one specific reason that would trigger this exception, so we allways ignored it

The thread in question work as follows:

using Oauth2 we connect to our Gmail Folder (via imapSSlStore) and perform a search on the Inbox Folder. Usually, after this search is over (it takes quite a few time, searching through ~12k mails) the remainder of the thread runs without error

With all the e-mails "in hand" we perform operations like "mail.getFrom()". I believe this kind of operation makes a new request to gmail Api, and sometimes we get error in this part too

These are the most common errors:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
```

(When attempting to perform the connectImap() )

`* BYE JavaMail Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection dropped by server?`

(this one can happen anywhere in the code)

```
A5 NO System Error (Failure)
A20 NO System Error
A15 NO System Error
```

No clue what those error means

My research points the major cause for similar errors to be "too many simultaneous connections" but i don't believe this is the case because the thread runs overnight, when there is no one else performing anything over IMAP

Comment: update with some code format

Comment: www.googleapis.com has nothign to do with the IMAP, maybe the OAuth server.  The second one can happen because the server closed the connection, maybe because you took too long to authenticate?  The other ones look just like the remote server has some problems.  You will need to build in more resistant code to retry whatever you were doing.